# How to find the max value over every N rows sorted by some field?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle12c

I have a table in Oracle 12c similar to:

```
CREATE TABLE test (
    id INT PRIMARY KEY,
    foo VARCHAR2(20),
    seconds int,
    system_dt DATE
);
```

With a set of data like

```
ABC, 10, 2016-01-01 00:00:01
ABC, 11, 2016-01-01 00:00:02
ABC, 5,  2016-01-01 00:35:54
ABC, 6, 2016-01-01 00:41:01
DEF, 15, 2016-01-01 00:00:02
DEF, 14, 2016-01-01 00:01:03
DEF, 51,  2016-01-01 00:36:55
DEF, 1, 2016-01-01 00:42:02
```

(It's important to note that `id`, `system_dt` (and apparently `rownum`) do not increment at any consistent value)

What I would like to do is sort this table by `foo, system_dt` and then find the `MAX(seconds)` over every N rows, grouped by `foo`.

So in the above example, where N is 2, the output would be:

```
ABC, 11, 2015-01-01 00:00:02
ABC, 6, 2016-01-01 00:41:01
DEF, 15, 2016-01-01 00:00:02
DEF, 51, 2016-01-01 00:36:55
```

---

I thought about using rownum, but the rownum increments aren't consistent in the following query:

```
SELECT foo, rownum, seconds, system_dt
FROM test
ORDER BY foo, system_dt
-----
ABC, 3, 20
ABC, 134 25
ABC, 137, 18
ABC, 5086, 15
ABC, 5098, 16
```

Comment: What is the desired result if the number of rows in the input, for a given FOO, is not exactly divisible by the group size? For example, if you have 20 values for FOO = 'ABC' and you divide into six rows at a time?

Comment: @mathguy I suppose it's ambiguous, but the way I'm implementing it in memory right now, I would take the max of the final two values in your example as opposed to discarding them. I guess I'm not too worried as what I'm doing is taking a sample of the worst running queries to put on a chart. But if you know of a way to implement it I would definitely use it!

Comment: Gordon's solution already does that. I was asking because I was thinking about a solution using MATCH_RECOGNIZE (since you are using Oracle 12, in which it is available).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would use `rownum` or `row_number()`:

```
select foo, max(seconds),
       max(system_dt) keep (dense_rank first order by seconds desc) as system_dt
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by foo order by system_dt) - 1 as seqnum
      from test t
     ) t
group by foo, trunc(seqnum / 2);
```

Comment: This appears to work on my data set thank you; would you please explain the choice of `seconds desc` in `dense_rank first order by seconds desc` ?

Comment: Gordon could have used `ORDER BY SECONDS` with KEEP (DENSE_RANK **LAST**). There would be a difference if `NULL` was allowed in the `SECONDS` column. In that case one could use `KEEP (DENSE_RANK LAST ORDER BY SECONDS NULLS FIRST`, or what Gordon wrote, which is essentially the same thing, just written differently.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that uses MATCH_RECOGNIZE (available since Oracle 12.1 only) to do the grouping by a fixed number of rows. Unfortunately, at least in 12.1 (the version I use) the aggregate function FIRST/LAST is not yet supported in MATCH_RECOGNIZE; if it was, everything could be done in match_recognize and GROUP BY would not be needed.

```
with
     test ( foo, seconds, system_dt ) as (
       select 'ABC', 10, to_date('2016-01-01 00:00:01', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') from dual union all
       select 'ABC', 11, to_date('2016-01-01 00:00:02', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') from dual union all
       select 'ABC',  5, to_date('2016-01-01 00:35:54', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') from dual union all
       select 'ABC',  6, to_date('2016-01-01 00:41:01', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') from dual union all
       select 'DEF', 15, to_date('2016-01-01 00:00:02', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') from dual union all
       select 'DEF', 14, to_date('2016-01-01 00:01:03', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') from dual union all
       select 'DEF', 51, to_date('2016-01-01 00:36:55', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') from dual union all
       select 'DEF',  1, to_date('2016-01-01 00:42:02', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') from dual
     )
-- end of test data (not part of the SQL query); query begins BELOW THIS LINE
select foo, max(seconds) as seconds, 
       max(system_dt) keep (dense_rank last order by seconds) as system_dt
from   test
match_recognize (
  partition by foo
  order by system_dt
  measures match_number() as mn
  all rows per match
  pattern ( a{2} | a+ $ )
  define a as 0 = 0
)
group by foo, mn
;

FOO  SECONDS  SYSTEM_DT
---  -------  -------------------
ABC       11  01/01/2016 00:00:02
ABC        6  01/01/2016 00:41:01
DEF       15  01/01/2016 00:00:02
DEF       51  01/01/2016 00:36:55
```